# Checkbox rapid selection not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox and textbox. When checkbox is clicked am assigning 500 to textbox and when checkbox is unchecked am doing 500-500 and assignig 0 to textbox.
My logic is working fine when i check checkbox slowly.
1.First time selection of checkbox: textbox value is 500.00
2.second time unselection of checkbox: textbox value is 0.00
3.Third time selection of checkbox: textbox value is 500.00

If i select/unselect checkbox rapidly am not getting desired result.
1.First time selection of checkbox: textbox value is 500.00
2.second time unselection of checkbox: textbox value is 0.00
3.Third time selection of checkbox: textbox value is 1000.00

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="txtAmount" name="txtAmount" /> <br />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectRec(chkRecord) {
        //debugger;
        $(chkRecord).prop('disabled', true);
        var dActualOrgAmount = $("#txtAmount").val();
        if (dActualOrgAmount == "" || dActualOrgAmount == '0.00')
            dActualOrgAmount = 0;

        if ($(chkRecord).prop('checked')) {
            dActualOrgAmount = eval(dActualOrgAmount) + eval(500);
            $("#txtAmount").val(eval(dActualOrgAmount).toFixed(2));
        }
        else {
            dActualOrgAmount = eval(dActualOrgAmount) - eval(500);
            $("#txtAmount").val(eval(dActualOrgAmount).toFixed(2));
        }
        $(chkRecord).prop('disabled', false);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vczn58cq/)** on **rapid click**

Comment: It is working fine in your JSfiddle example. All your code i have copied into my asp.net application still not working. I selecting checkbox rapidly 3 times i can see the values in textbox as 500 , 1000 and 0.00. Please what could be the reason

Comment: Cannot tell buddy since its not replicable!

Comment: The reason could be the Browser. It works fine on Chrome, not on IE9 and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can try This one.

```js
function selectRec(chkRecord) {
        //debugger;
        $(chkRecord).prop('disabled', true);
        var dActualOrgAmount = $("#txtAmount").val();
        var dGetAmount = 0;
  
        if (dActualOrgAmount == "" || dActualOrgAmount == '0.00')
            dActualOrgAmount = 0;

        if ($(chkRecord).prop('checked')) {
            
            dGetAmount = eval(dActualOrgAmount) + eval(500);
            $("#txtAmount").val(eval(dGetAmount).toFixed(2));
        }
        else {
           
            dGetAmount = eval(dActualOrgAmount) - eval(500);
            $("#txtAmount").val(eval(dGetAmount).toFixed(2));
        }
        $(chkRecord).prop('disabled', false);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txtAmount" name="txtAmount" /> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkcheck" value="Click" onclick="selectRec(this)" name="Click" /> <br />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want ZERO when checkbox is not checked.

Comment: I used onchange event instead onclick its working fine in all browsers.